# IFrame showing blank/empty content in IE and Firefox --

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4, embed

As you can read - my question is very basic. Probably too simple, but I can't get this to behave in the fashion I desire.
My main application is a .NET MVC5 application. In one of the views I want to embed and show another webpage through and iframe.

So
Iframe html code --

```
<div class="row mb-5">
                    <iframe src="https://www.sellcodes.com/pro_indigo" style="width: 750px; height: 450px;">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
```

But when I run it, that other webpage does not show up in my iFrame. It is empty. For reference see the image --> [ https://imagebin.ca/v/5B4tCphd7HDK ]. It is simply blank. I cross checked with IE also, just to be sure if that's a browser issue. But it is blank there too.

What's the grief? What did I miss please?

UPDATE:
I added this in my web.config.

Still doesn't do it. No improvement.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: How about console - did it wrote some info? Might be due the [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: hi @Jax-p yeah - this is the related error I am getting in the console:    Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “sameorigin” from “https://sellcodes.com/pro_indigo”, site does not permit cross-origin framing from “http://localhost:1579/Home/Services”.       What to do? I thought loading any other webpage in a iFrame was pretty basic.....

Comment: You have to setup your headers to accept iframe from any site or explicit domain by [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: any pointers, code blocks etc. on that that I can implement @Jax-p  ?

Comment: It's about application/web/server configuration. I don't know .NET so you have to find how to setup CORS and X-frames on .NET. Maybe [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/08/set-x-frame-options-asp-net-core/) could be helpful.

Comment: I updated my code @Jax-p . Pl take a look; thanks for the link, but it's for .NET Core, mine is .Net MVC 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207116/discussion-between-prabir-choudhury-and-jax-p).